# Selenium Upload a file using button type and button tag instead of file

Tags: selenium, button, upload

I have a webpage where I click on a button and an open dialog it's opened and I should select the file to upload. After that, a pop up is displayed saying OK or KO.

I'm able to upload files when the there are files types. But in this case, the element where I click it's:

```
    <
    button type="button" read-file="_.partial(submitLang, selectedLang)" id="import-lang" class="btn btn-default"><
    /button>
```

For the rest of the application, I use this and it works:

```
    WebElement element = getPage().findElementById(id);
    element.sendKeys(absoluteFile);
```

But for button types and button tag it doesn't work.

How can I do it? The tests are running on a Linux machine
Thanks a lot!

More info!!

Hi all,
The whole process is: (see image at http://imageshack.com/a/img540/6237/JoTQng.png)

1. Click on Import button
2. A dialog is opened and I select a .json file and click Open
3. An alert is displayed saying "Text properties have been updated".

We are using angular for the frontend and all are REST calls.
We don't have any "file=type". All three are buttons. You can found more code at
http://imageshack.com/a/img633/7299/BQhP7o.png

Comment: How you are creating webelement using tag or type attribute. Please post them also.

Comment: can you share some more of your HTML? -> see my answer

Comment: Hi all,
The whole process is: (see image at http://imageshack.com/a/img540/6237/JoTQng.png)

 1. Click on Import button
 2. A dialog is opened and I select a .json file and click Open
 3. An alert is displayed saying "Text properties have been updated".


We are using angular for the frontend and all are REST calls.
We don't have any "file=type". All three are buttons. You can found more code at
http://imageshack.com/a/img633/7299/BQhP7o.png

Answer (score 2):

For a file upload with selenium, you need to **find an input tag with the type "file"**. 
Have a look at your HTML and search for it.

When you found it, the rest is pretty straightforward:

Let's say this input-element has id="import"

```
driver.findElement(By.id("import")).sendKeys(absoluteFile);
```

*If you run into problems, please post more of your HTML, then I can have a look at it.*

Comment: The problem is that this element is not type file :( Maybe the solutions is ask to my frontend developer to change button for file :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, clicking on the button made an  element appear in the HTML code, I assume due to javascript.

I clicked on the  element (which both opens a file upload window and adds the  to the HTML), and immediately after send the keys to the input element.

This creates the problem of having to close the newly opened file upload window, however this is not a problem when using --headless mode on google chrome.
I do not have a solution to close this window if you are not in headless mode for your chosen browser.